# Understanding unquoteDecl in Agda

Tags: agda

I'm trying to understand Agda's built in reflection mechanisms, so I decided to write a simple function that takes a string for an identifier,
a quoted type, and a quoted term, and simply defines a term of the given type with the given string identifier. Thus, I wrote the following:

```
testDefineName' : String → TC Type → TC Term → TC ⊤
testDefineName' s t a =
   bindTC (freshName s)
     (λ n → bindTC t
     (λ t' → bindTC a
     (λ a' → (bindTC (declareDef (arg (arg-info visible relevant) n) t')
     (λ _ → defineFun n ((clause [] a') ∷ []))))))

unquoteDecl = (testDefineName' "test" (quoteTC ℕ) (quoteTC zero))
```

This type-checks, but, when I try to use "test" elsewhere I get a `Not in scope: test` error.

The [documentation](http://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language/reflection.html#unquoting-declarations) for `unquoteDecl` is kind of opaque. Appaently declarations should be of the form

```
unquoteDecl x_1 x_2 ... x_n = m
```

where the `x_i` are `Name`s, and `m` has type `TC \top`, so maybe what I was trying to do isn't actually possible, but I still don't understand how this mechanism works: if `m` has to be of type `TC ⊤`, and thus cannot be a function of the names `x_1 x_2 ... x_n`, I don't see how it is possible to bring any new names into scope using `unquoteDecl` at all!

So, to sum up:

Is it possible to define a function like mine using Agda's reflection mechanism so that I can bring new names into scope using a `String` argument? What I want is something like:

```
<boilerplate code for unquoting> testDefineName' "test" (quoteTC ℕ) (quoteTC zero)
test' : ℕ
test' = test
```

to compile (i.e. I can actually use the new name, "test")

and if not, by what mechanism can `m` make use of the names `x_1 ... x_n`? Can `m` actually have a type like `List Name → TC ⊤`, contrary to the documentation?

Comment: Please include the list of import statements in these kind of posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [the way Ulf uses `unquoteDecl`](https://github.com/UlfNorell/agda-prelude/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=unquoteDecl&type=), I have the impression that you need to list on the LHS the names which are going to extend the scope.

The problem with your setup is that you don't know the `Name` as you generate a fresh one from a `String` and have no way of getting hold of it AFAIK. I have the impression that `freshName` is only supposed to be used to generate internal names from inside a tactic.

If you make `testDefineName'` take a `Name` rather than a `String` then everything works out:

```
testDefineName' : Name → TC Type → TC Term → TC ⊤
testDefineName' n t a = bindTC t
               $ λ t' → bindTC a
               $ λ a' → bindTC (declareDef (arg (arg-info visible relevant) n) t')
               $ λ _  → defineFun n ((clause [] a') ∷ [])

unquoteDecl test = testDefineName' test (quoteTC ℕ) (quoteTC zero)
```